# Javascript redirect loop

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some old url redirection with javascript.

My old urls in Google index are something like `domain.com/#!about/c3g8`. My new url for about us page is like `domain.com/#about` since I have change my site to one paged site.

My old site has had 4 pages without including root page. Each page has had a unique ending. They are -

```
/c3g8
/cjg9
/cee5
/cce3
```

The redirections cannot be done in .htaccess because they contain hash(#) character in them. Therefore, I have no choice but javascript. My current redirect js code is as follow

```
if(document.URL.indexOf(/!|\/c3g8|\/cjg9|\/cee5|\/cce3/)) {
    var url_new = document.URL.replace(/!|\/c3g8|\/cjg9|\/cee5|\/cce3/,'');
    window.location = url_new;
    break;
}
```

All inner pages redirect properly but home page became a redirect loop and until I press `Esc` key twice.

I have this `$('a[href^=#]').bind("click", function(event){....` code in my js too. How can I redirect without leading to a redirect loop?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing regex matching and `indexOf`. The `if` condition is always going to evaluate to `-1` which is truthy, so the the redirect always happens.

Use `regex.test()` instead, and use the `g` modifier to tell it to replace all instances...

```
if(/!|\/c3g8|\/cjg9|\/cee5|\/cce3/.test(document.URL)) {
    var url_new = document.URL.replace(/!|\/c3g8|\/cjg9|\/cee5|\/cce3/g,'');
    window.location = url_new;
    break;
}
```

Comment: It escaped the redirect loop but not redirecting when I click from Google's index. Google shows `domain.com/#!about/cjg9` and it landed to same url. I have to refresh one time to get to correct url `domain.com/#about`

Comment: When are you executing that code? I would put an `alert(document.URL)` just before the `if` and see what it says (if anything) when you come from google - should give you an insight.

Comment: It alert old url from Google index. When I click `ok` then nothing happen. I was using `$(document).ready(function() {......` and putting your code in this.

Comment: Ok, that eliminates a bunch of possibilities. So, if you `alert(url_new)` just before setting window.location what do you get?

Comment: Thank you! It really helped.

It alert `domain.com/#!about/cjg9` first time and `domain.com/#about/cjg9` next. The code just strip `!` from the url. Then I realize it is because of I'm using OR operator `|` for all. Therefore, I've change the code to something like this.

`if(/!|\/c3g8|\/cjg9|\/cee5|\/cce3/.test(document.URL)) {
     var url_new = document.URL.replace('!','');
     var url_new = url_new.replace(/\/c3g8|\/cjg9|\/cee5|\/cce3/,'');
     window.location = url_new;
 }`

Comment: Actually, you could keep the original and just add a g to the end of the regex to tell it to match all occurrences, I'll edit it in

Comment: Thank you! I'm using your code now. Working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var url_new = document.URL.replace(/!|\/c3g8|\/cjg9|\/cee5|\/cce3/,'');
if(document.URL !== url_new){
    window.location = url_new;
}
```

Comment: It escaped the redirect loop but not redirecting when I click from Google's index. Google shows `domain.com/#!about/cjg9` and it landed to same url. I have to refresh one time to get to correct url `domain.com/#about`